# Xamarin.forms: using own class object in code and xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

So i have my class "Datenbank" with the ObservableCollection "Liste" in it. 
I need to use the values of the Liste in a ListView and at the same time be able to edit it in code, but i wasn't able to do both at the same time.
When i create a Datenbank object, im unable to use it in my Listview and if i use only the class Datenbank and its constructor for the Listview, i cant edit it in the  code. I guess making Datenbank static might be a solution, but i wasnt able to make it work (even with other posts on the static topic).
Could you guys please help me on this one? Thank You :)

Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SportAchievements"
             x:Class="SportAchievements.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="Silver"           
             >


    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        < local:Datenbank />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Liste}"
              HasUnevenRows="True"
                  x:Name="LV1"
                 BackgroundColor="Silver"
              ItemTapped="ListView_OnItemTapped"
              >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout >
                            <Label Text="{Binding MyName}" BackgroundColor="Gray" TextColor="DodgerBlue"></Label>
                            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
                                <Label  Text="{Binding Points, StringFormat= '\Punkte: {0\} '}"></Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Info}"></Label>
                                      />
                            </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Datenbank class:

```
namespace SportAchievements
{
    public class Datenbank
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Achievement> Liste;


        public Datenbank()
        {
            Liste = new ObservableCollection<Achievement>
            {
                new Achievement
                    {
                        MyName= "10 Liegestützen",
                        Info="bla bla bla",
                        Points =1,
                        IsVisible = false,
                        Done = false
                    }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

and here in the mainpage i want to edit the Liste in Datenbank:

```
namespace SportAchievements
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public void Load_all()
        {
            var vm = BindingContext as Datenbank;
            foreach (Achievement myAch in vm.Liste)
            {
                string myreturnvalue = "";
                Load_key(myAch.MyName, ref myreturnvalue, "false");
                myAch.Done = Convert.ToBoolean(myreturnvalue);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can only bind to public properties.  Liste is public, but NOT a property

Comment: @Jason thanks, i made Liste to a public property, but i am still not sure how to finish this. Do i need to make Datenbank static or do i need to make an Object of Datenbank? Sorry, im new to xaml and failed with both ideas (probably at the xaml part?).

Comment: You haven't actually explained what's wrong.  Your code appears correct (other than what I already mentioned) but without a clear explanation of the problem there's not much else I can do.

Comment: @Jason the preview of the listview is emty when it shouldnt be.  let me ask it this way: does < local:Datenbank /> call the constructor of Datenbank? If so how do i call that object in code/ how do i attach a name to it?

Comment: the previewer just displays the XAML, it does not execute the code.  You need to actually run it to see if the code works.  If you want to access the ViewModel in code then assign it in code, not XAML.

Comment: i see: <x:Name="abc" local:Datenbank /> is wrong, <local:Datenbank x:Name="abc" /> not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did the job for me :)
Then i can call abc from code without problems